# How to refresh component in reactnative using redux pattern?

Tags: react-native, redux, components

I am using Redux pattern, I have problem in state management. 
Condition: When i successfully submitted form data from action.js with actonTypes.SUBMITSUCCESS. and i update view according to the status send from reducer.The problem is that when i press back from that component and again navigate to UpdateDate component the submit status remain same and every time it shows success whenever i navigate to that component.

Answer (score 0):

in your reducer, after successfully sending the form data, is the state set back to its initial value?

also, I like to create an action "clearForm" and call it in the *componentWillMount()* to set the state back to is initial value:

```
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.clearEntityForm();
  }
```